# tex4ht: conflict between `\[`..`\]` and `split` environment

Tags: amsmath, tex4ht, tex4ebook

MWE:

```latex
\documentclass{amsart}

\begin{document}
split, also from amsmath,
similar alignment to align, but the whole construct fits within
equation (or other display math) and is numbered as a unit.
\[
  \begin{split}
    a& =b+c-d\\
    & \quad +e-f\\
    & =g+h\\
    & =i\\
  \end{split}
\]
\end{document}
```

Run `tex4ebook` with error

```
[ERROR]   htlatex: ./test.tex   13   Package amsmath Error: \begin{split} won't work here.
```

If we replace `\[` and `\]` by `equation*` environment, then there is no error. Note that we already have

```latex
\Configure{[]}{\begin{equation*}}{\end{equation*}}{}
```

in the configure file. I need to understand the reason (and hopefully a perfection) of this.